# Rails Minified (Compiled) Assets in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

How do I get my assets rendered in their minified (compiled) form in Rails development mode?

I have about few dozens of asset files, and because they are served one after another it all takes pretty long before the page loads in development. I believe if I keep them compiled and getting served from that would speed up my page load time(I know this is not ideal when I am specifically working on assets).

Here is my style and script tags in the layout

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'all'  %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'all' %>
```

And I've also ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile:nondigest`

But I still see the assets being rendered one after another. Please help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's quite simple.
You only need to add/change the following line in your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

And restart your rails server.

Comment: I still had to mention , :debug => false on stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag calls. Can you confirm you are able to get this working without explicitly setting :debug false?

Comment: Absolutely. I have the same configuration.

Comment: And if I set the :debug => false, it doesnt require config.assets.compress = true either! thats weird then

Comment: Have you restarted your server to work with the new configuration?

Comment: This answer is not correct.  You don't want to turn on compression, you want to turn off debug mode.  To turn off debug mode in your development.rb: `config.assets.debug = false`.

Comment: Gabe is right. Need to turn off assets.debug. If either of you could enter this as answer I can accept that. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Works perfectly. I needed to toggle this so I could test in IE8 (which limits the num of stylesheets it will load).

Answer (score 3):

On Rails 4.2.1 works with this configuration:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
# config.assets.debug = true
```

With this configuration, the `precompile` will make all JS and CSS files minified to me in the `development` environment.